# Bulk saving objects SQLAlchemy for second table create surplus id s

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Table:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender = Column(String)
    name = relationship("Name", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    location = relationship("Location", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    email = Column(String)
    login = relationship("Login", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    dob = relationship("Dob", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    registered = relationship("Registered", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    phone = Column(String)
    cell = Column(String)
    id_person = relationship("IdPerson", uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    nat = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'(id:{self.id}, gender:{self.name})'
```

I have JSON file that contains **1000 rows** persons data (and double and triple nested "tables").

I created a function that create a lists of eg. genders from JSON file.
I created a function that insert data from that list into the db.

```
def bulk_save_obj_gender():
    index = 0
    persons_gender = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        per = Person(gender=all_genders[index])
        persons_gender.append(per)
        index += 1

    session.bulk_save_objects(persons_gender, return_defaults=True)
    for gender in persons_gender:
        assert gender.id is not None
    session.add_all(persons_gender)
    session.commit()

def bulk_save_obj_email():
    index = 0
    persons_emails = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        per = Person(email=all_emails[index])
        persons_emails.append(per)
        index += 1

    session.bulk_save_objects(persons_emails, return_defaults=True)
     for email in persons_emails:
         assert email.id is not None
    session.add_all(persons_emails)
    session.commit()
```

and what I see in the *.db is that I have 1-1000 id of genders (and NULL emails column) and 1001-2000 id of emails.

I wonder how to create a function that insert that emails into existing id from 1 to 2000. To connect gender and emails by their id.

I'm not sure I can describe it well.

[screenshot-of-db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqXSb.png)

When I changed code to simple SQL query it works fine:

```
def populate_data_using_sqlite_query():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('persons.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    for i in range(count_indexes()):
        gend = all_genders[i]
        email = all_emails[i]
        params = (i, gend, email)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO person (id, gender, email) VALUES (?,?,?)", params)
    conn.commit()


populate_data_using_sqlite_query()
```

but I really wanna do that using ORM.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to avoid email null columns and to make sure that they are mapped with gender.

```
def bulk_save_persons():
    index = 0
    persons = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        person = Person(gender=all_genders[index], email=all_emails[index])
        persons.append(person)
        index += 1

    session.add_all(persons)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you !